# How to make a visible area in unity3d

Tags: unity

the simple way to explain it is an image

[image]

I want to have a black background and to show only a small area around player. Which way I have to look? I have no clue where to start searching :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to use GUI. Have a big square about 16x times the size of the screen with a circle in the middle of it. This is so if your playing on the TV, you wont see the stuff behind the background.

Comment: well its an idea :) I will try it